# How to find method, linked to NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, lldb

I have Cocoa application, with a code, partially hidden in a framework. I need to press NSButton programmatically.

When I use `[myNSButton performClick:self]`, it behave differently, that when I press button physically. So I decide to find method, that linked to that NSButton.
Looks like trick with `[UIButton allTargets]` is working only for iOS, but not for NSButton on macOS.
Do you have ideas, how to find method, that linked to NSButton ?

Comment: What's `button.action`? Also, `performClick:` is calling on a simple click, but there is `button.sendAction(on:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428972-sendaction you can test the various events to see which one is causing your behavior.

Comment: How is the button behaving differently?

Comment: I found, that it was my mistake, I got id of wrong NSButton. Now performClick behave the same as physical press. But still don't find, how to find method, linked to NSButton. Any lldb command/tricks ?

Comment: @Larme already gave you a pointer - `NSButton` is a subclass of `NSControl` which contains [`action`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428956-action?language=objc) & [`target`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428885-target?language=objc) properties. If the `target` property is `nil` then the application follows the responder chain looking for an object that can respond to the message.

Comment: yes this is what I need! 'po (SEL)[myNSButton action]' gives me needed selector!